# Why does $\frac{x^n}{n^x}$ stop growing at the approximate value of $\pi (n)$?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, exponential-function

I noticed while playing around with these functions that $n^x$ will start slow and then speed up really fast in its growth rate. While $x^n$ grows more slowly, but faster than $n^x$ at the start. Coincidentally, $\frac {d}{dx} \frac{x^n}{n^x}$ will equal zero at $\frac {n}{\ln n}~\pi (n)$ 

 
Is there a reason for this or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: How did you come up with $\pi (n)$? The derivative is equal to $0$ when $x = \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$

Comment: It's a coincidence.  You could write a million simple problems with $n/\log n$ as their solution which have nothing to do with $\pi(n)$.  This is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a coincidence. You might like the following excellent article on generating coincidences:

[Seemingly Remarkable Mathematical Coincidences Are Easy to Generate](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3903/cdce91c73af50b97f24e7825932139867073.pdf)